# Delete and merge Partition

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, disk-format

My MacBook's HDD has 2 partitions. One has OS X 10.8 installed, the other one 10.9. I'd like to delete the first partition and merge the free space afterwards to the 2nd partition.

What's the easiest way to do this? Can I use `diskutil eraseVolume/mergePartitions`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up wiping the 1st partition, reinstalling 10.9 on it, migrating the data from the 2nd partition onto it using Time Machine and then removing the 2nd partition using Disk Utility.

I didn't try using *Carbon Copy Cloner* or *DuperDuper* to move the entire partition directly, because I wanted a working OS X Recovery Partition, but I recon that could probably work as well.

Answer (score 1):

### [iPartition](http://www.coriolis-systems.com/iPartition.php)

For all my partitioning, I use and recommend iPartition. It will allow you to resize partitions without deleting any data. It also works for Boot Camp volumes and other PC disks. It will automatically move partitions if necessary to allow resizing into free space that is located before the partition.

> With iPartition, resizing a partition is as simple as selecting it, grabbing the resize handle and dragging. Not only that, but if you have several operations to perform, iPartition lets you queue them up and run them one after another, so you can have a cup of coffee while iPartition works. This feature, coupled with iPartition’s ability to automatically rearrange your existing partitions when necessary, makes iPartition the easiest partitioning tool that you’ll ever use.
>
> [image]

Comment: iPartition won't change the HDD that's been booted from.

Comment: @Till iPartition lets you create a boot disk to allow operations on the startup disk :)